# AWS EC2 windows user getting logged off closing all console programmes

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We are facing a strange issue. We have built a AWS EC2 instance windows OS. 
On this EC2 instance we are running console application with high I/O. Instance type is I3.4Xlarge. After every 3 to 4 hours user session by which applications are running get logged off and closing all console application. The MAX CPU and Memory utilization we have noted is 45% and 50%.

Any help on this?

Comment: Is the remote session being actively used? I'm just wondering whether the RDP connection times-out after a period of inactivity? Or is it happening mid-session while being actively used?

Comment: No Remote session is not actively used. After running the processes we close RDP.

Comment: If RDP is not connected, how do you know that applications "get logged off"? This sounds like something related to the browser or operating system. It would not be related to Amazon EC2 since the instance itself is still running.